# Why can't I input a filename for opening in c?

Tags: c, debugging, file-io, user-input, scanf

I have been attempting to debug this program with my limited knowledge, and have compared it with other programs in which i've used the same methods to retrieve a filename for opening. However, it seems that for some odd reason the program does not recieve user input for filename, sometimes getting caught in some sort of an elusive loop.

I have used both:
    scanf("%s\n", filename);

and:
    gets(filename);

(i know gets is "dangerous" but this is a program that is not going to be distributed, it is an assignment in a college level class)

here is the main() function and the getssn() function (which does get user input successfully):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 19
#define MAXR 999

//structure defining a given client
typedef struct person {
unsigned int ssn, age, height, weight, income;
char name[MAXS+1], job[MAXS+1], religion[MAXS+1], major[MAXS+1], minor[MAXS+1], gender;
}PERSON;


//get and check for ssn validity
int getssn(){
int num;

printf("\nSSN: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

if(num<=99999999 || num>999999999){
    printf("\nPlease input a valid SSN.\n");
    return 0;
}
else
    return num;
}

//read the specified file and check for the input ssn
int readfile(FILE *fptr, PERSON **rptr, int *count){
int v=0, i, j;
char n2[MAXS+1], b[2]=" ";

for(i=0; i<MAXR; i++){
    j=i;

    //read the file in chunks
    if(fscanf(fptr, "%c\n%d\n%19s %19s\n%d\n%19s\n%d\n%19s\n%19s\n%d\n%d\n%19s\n\n",
              &rptr[j]->gender, &rptr[j]->ssn, rptr[j]->name, n2, &rptr[j]->age, 
              rptr[j]->job, &rptr[j]->income, rptr[j]->major, rptr[j]->minor,
              &rptr[j]->height, &rptr[j]->weight, rptr[j]->religion)==EOF)
        i=MAXR;

    //make first and last name one element
    strcat(rptr[j]->name, b);
    strcat(rptr[j]->name, n2);

    //if we find a match, tell main the id
    if(rptr[MAXR]->ssn==rptr[j]->ssn)
        v=j;
}

//count how many clients we have
*count=j;

return v;
}

//commpare age and income
int cmpai(PERSON rec1, PERSON rec2){
int a=0, inc=0;

if(rec1.age<=(rec2.age+10) && rec1.age>=(rec2.age-10))
    a=1;
if(rec1.income<=(rec2.income+10000) && rec1.income>=(rec2.income-10000))
    inc=1;

if(a==1 && inc==1)
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;


}

//compare hobbies
int cmph(PERSON rec1, PERSON rec2){
if(strcmp(rec1.major,rec2.major)==0 && strcmp(rec1.minor, rec2.minor)==0)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

//compare weight, height, and religion
int cmpwhr(PERSON rec1, PERSON rec2){
int w=0, h=0, r=0;
double n1, n2;

n1=rec1.height;
n2=rec2.height;
if(n1<=(n2*1.1) && n1>=(n2*0.9))
    h=1;

n1=rec1.weight;
n2=rec2.weight;
if(n1<=(n2*1.1) && n1>=(n2*0.9))
    w=1;

if(strcmp(rec1.religion, rec2.religion)==0)
    r=1;

if(r==1 && h==1 && w==1)
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;
}

//sort the ids in ascending order by ssn for proper output
void sort(int *A, int count){
int i, j, temp;

for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    for(j=0; j<count; j++)
        if(A[i+1]<A[i]){
            temp=A[i];
            A[i]=A[i+1];
            A[i+1]=temp;
        }
}

//display the possible matches in ascending ssn order
void display(int matches[], PERSON rec[], int count){
int i;

for(i=0; i<count; i++){
    if(matches[i]==rec[i].ssn)
        printf("%s\n", rec[i].name);
}
 }



int main(){
int valid=-1, i, counter=0, *c=&counter, id[MAXR-1], totalmatches;
char filename[MAXS];
FILE *fp;
PERSON record[MAXR+1], *rp[MAXR+1];

//get a ssn from the user
do{
    record[MAXR].ssn=getssn();
}while(record[MAXR].ssn==0);

//get a filename
printf("Name of file of records: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
printf("%s", filename);

//open the file, if possible
if((fp=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)
    perror(filename);
else{
    printf("test");
    for(i=0; i<=MAXR; i++){
        rp[i]=&record[i];
        id[i]=0;
    }

    //read the file, find the matching ssn
    valid=readfile(fp, rp, c);

    //check if the ssn is in the file, if not tell the user
    if(valid<0){
        printf("\nSSN %d is not found in file %s.\n", record[MAXR].ssn, filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        //check for matches and count how many we have
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
            if(i!=valid)
                if(record[valid].gender!= record[i].gender)
                    if(cmpai(record[valid], record[i])==1 || cmph(record[valid], record[i])==1 || cmpwhr(record[valid], record[i])==1){
                        id[i]=record[i].ssn;
                        totalmatches+=1;                        
                    }
        }
        //if we have matches sort them and display them, otherwise tell the user he has no match in this group
        if(totalmatches>0){
            sort(id, counter);
            display(id, record, counter);
        }
        else 
            printf("\nNo matches.\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
}
```

This is the current **input**(single quotes)/output:

```
run
[Switching to process 6956]
Running…

SSN: '111223333'
Name of file of records: 'clients.txt'
clients.txttest
Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

Comment: If you believe the problem is with getting the filename from the user, then all the code to do with opening and reading from the file is irrelevant!  Try deleting all that code from your snippet.

Comment: @Kabir, please be more descriptive about the symptoms. My understanding is as follows, please confirm or reject these facts directly:    You run the program that has `scanf("%s\n", filename)`, then you type `clients.txt`, then you hit the Enter key, then nothing happens? Then you sit patiently until you hit Ctrl+D? What then happens when you hit Ctrl+D?   If this is so, I urge you to remove the "\n" immediately.

Comment: after hitting ctrl+D it prints "clients.txt", meaning it did recieve the input, it just never decided to stop receiving input. i'll try without the \n and tell you what happens

Comment: without the \n it prints the next printf line immediately then returns an exit code of 0

Comment: Excellent. `scanf ("%s\n", s)` means "Scan some non-whitespace characters into s, and then wait until the user has entered _more_ whitespace. "\n" (and "\t" and " ") means "wait until the user has entered more whitespace".  This is why it's best to just use `scanf("%s")`

Comment: For the record, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is zero, not one.  This is because there's only one kind of success, but there could be many different kinds of failure: for instance, `grep`'s exit status is 0 if it found at least one match, 1 if it found no matches, and 2 if it couldn't open a file.

Comment: Hi @Kabir, I will not have time to think about this further. I would like to respectully make a number of suggestions. First, your program is a very large program, you should not be trying to build a huge program in one go and hope that it works. You should build build a small working program and build up from there. Second, you should put `printf`s throughout your code, in between every line of code - I don't think we have any idea where you code is. This is basic programming advice; even when I was very new to programming, I knew that there are basic things I should do (like `printf`s).

Answer (score 1):

You should your getssn() function. You need to put in a return statement.

```
int getssn(){
   int num;

   printf("\nSSN: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   return num;  // You MUST put this in.
}
```

This will improve this code:

```
do{
  record[MAXR].ssn=getssn();
}while(record[MAXR].ssn==0);
```

If you forget the return, then getssn() might return 0 forever.

You should also tell us what **exact** output you are seeing. You should copy all the output into your question also.

Answer (score 0):

Never use any of the `scanf` family of functions; they don't give you nearly enough control over what happens on invalid input, and `scanf("%s")` is just as dangerous as `gets`.

But this is probably not your immediate problem.  That's much more likely to be a case of trying to open a file by partial pathname when it's not in the current working directory.  Try typing in the full pathname (`/home/kabir/filename`, `C:\users\kabir\filename`, sort of thing).  Also, changing

```
printf("\nCould not open file\n");
```

to

```
perror(filename);
```

will give you more information when things go wrong.

Comment: I never get to the "could not open file" case, the program enters the "else" statement if i input the end-of-input character by hitting ctrl-d...however when I do not enter ctrl-d the program hangs as if it is waiting for input. when I go step-by-step it says "stepping into..." indefinitely

Comment: ... that's bizarre.  What environment is this? How are you running the program?

Comment: i've tried both xcode and gcc, and i've tested my previous programs in both environments using the same input method (both previous programs used gets(filename) instead of scanf but i doubt thats the issue)

Comment: by gcc i mean i used terminal and ssh'd to a campus computer center to compile using gcc

Comment: @Kabir: if your code is entering the "else" portion of that statement, then *that's* the code you need to show us, otherwise we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: look at the comment on the other answer

Comment: added the whole main function

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
scanf("%s", filename)
```

i.e. remove the `\n`

Unrelated, but you seem to have forgotten `return num` at the end of `getssn()`.

Looking at your current code (8:10 pm Dublin/London time), you should use this instead:

```
//get a filename
printf("Name of file of records: ");
//scanf("%s", filename);
printf("scanned file: <%s>\n", filename);

//open the file, if possible
if((fp=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)
    perror(filename);
else{
    printf("test\n");
    ...
```

Comment: and i've tried
    scanf("%s", filename)

yielding the same results

Comment: Could you try putting in `printf("scanned file: <%s>", filename);` immediately after the scanf? This is the natural way to ensure a string has been read correctly. And what happens inside the `else {...}`? That is probably the most important part of your code.

Comment: the first statement in else is a printf statement, and it never gets there unless i define the file when i initialize 'filename' (e.g. char filename[MAXS]="clients.txt";)...when i do this, the program executes flawlessly in no time at all

Comment: it only hangs when I attempt to have the user input anything

Comment: This is why I need you to put a printf **immediately** after the scanf(), in order to ensure the scan is correct. If you can verify that "clients.txt" is in file_name after you type "clients.txt", then we have some evidence to discuss. `scanf("%s", filename); printf("scanned file: <%s>", filename); `

Comment: done, but it has no effect, program still hangs before the printf.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what happens when you run the program now? What characters do you type, and what output do you see? Do you see `scanned file: <clients.txt>`?

Comment: **Update**: I just noticed a mistake in my comment about 15 minutes ago. I forget to put a "\n" at the end of the printf! `printf("scanned file: <%s>\n", filename);` You should almost always have a newline at the end of a printf in order to ensure that the line is immediately flushed to output. It's embarrasing that I'm noticing extra newlines in scanf, when I forgot a newline myself :-)

Comment: yes, i see that, however the file itself now seems that the rest of the code is being "ignored", i'm testing it step by step right now

Comment: Could you update your question to include the code you are working on now?

Comment: done, updated it but it looks like its exiting with 0, which is no good, EXIT_SUCCESS = 1, right?

Comment: looks like its not going into the other functions it should enter

Comment: You need to have **both** the scanf and the printf. `scanf("%s", filename);
printf("scanned file: <%s>\n", filename);`

Comment: sorry, i commented that out for debugging, must've posted the wrong one

Comment: i'm just gonna post the whole thing. Some of these bugs are annoying the shit out of me, i fixed them all and now they're back! oh noes!